# MySQL comparing total sums to all sums in expenses, income, savings (3 different tables) as percentage per month

Tags: mysql, select, union

I'm trying to create a query which allows me to get a percentage value for each month comparing expenses, incomes and savings whith each other. I'm using MySQL database.

Example to the tables and the query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78b360/1

So far I'm able to get the SUM per month from each table:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT sum(amount) AS Total, month(date) AS Month FROM expenses
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(amount), month(date) FROM income
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(amount), month(date) FROM savings
GROUP BY month(date)) as grand_total
```

result:

```
|   Total | Month |
|---------|-------|
| 1323232 |     9 |
|  300101 |     9 |
|   20000 |     9 |
|       1 |    10 |
```

what I'm trying to achieve is something like this if I only look at month 9 :

```
|   Total | Month | Percent
|---------|-------|--------
| 1323232 |     9 |     81%
|  300101 |     9 |     18%
|   20000 |     9 |      1%
```

Can you please help me out here? I have looked at many-many answers on stackoverflow and other sites but could not find what I exactly needed. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current query is that you are not aggregating by month in the `expenses` or `income` tables, only for the `savings` table.  The final `GROUP BY` does *not* apply to everything.

I think what you need to do here is to first aggregate by month over each of the three tables, union together those results, and then aggregate a second time by month to get the grand total for each month.

```
SELECT
    month,
    SUM(total) AS month_total
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM expenses
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONTH(date), SUM(amount)
    FROM income
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONTH(date), SUM(amount)
    FROM savings
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) t
-- WHERE month = 9         -- or whichever months you want to see
GROUP BY
    month
ORDER BY
    month
```

Comment: I thought the final `GROUP BY` does apply. Sorry. Now I can aggregate to get the percentages. Nice!

Comment: How would I go about to aggregate a second time by month to get the grand total for each month?

Comment: Yes, I got that. But how would I get to this:

`         |   Total | Month | Percent
         |---------|-------|--------
expenses | 1323232 |     9 |     81%
income   |  300101 |     9 |     18%
savings  |   20000 |     9 |      1%
`

Comment: Is the sub grouping necessary or advantageous?

Comment: Yes, sub grouping allows me to see the values for each month. The logic behind it is to see how much was the income, how much were the expenses and how much for savings in percent value.

Comment: @Gee I can't readily think of a query for that which would not be hideous in MySQL.  I think you might want to have just one table for expenses, income, and savings, which would make your reporting a whole lot easier.  Being forced to write big ugly queries might indicate bad table/database design.

Comment: Now I'm getting the grand total, but how do I get the sub total and % for the expence, income, and savings values for every month or selected month?

Comment: I guess you don't read the comments, but I said that I won't write that query, because it would be huge and ugly.  I recommend putting all the line items into a single table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you. Yeah, I thought about this too. I did read the comment, sorry.